# How to use Sublime Text 3 SCSS syntax highlighting with existing CSS completion

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way to use only the syntax highlighting from a package?

I really love the ST3 completion that I have for CSS (I think its emmet, not sure, but this isnt important).

So I want to use this with SCSS files but use syntax highlighting from another package.

Every package that does syntax highlighting wants to use its own tab completion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't make sure about your question, but I'm using the "Syntax Highlighting for Sass". It's solve my problems.

All autocompletes from .css could be possible in to .scss

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not acceptable on Stack Exchange sites. The link may change or become unreachable in the future, and without a summary of what the link contains this answer would be useless. Please summarize what is in the link (**don't** just copy and paste) and use the link solely for reference. If you remove the link and the answer cannot stand on its own, it is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but it's not really good:

tweak the `css_completions.py` file in in the CSS package. Look for `selector_scope` and you get something like the following

#### For example

```
selector_scope = "source.css - meta.selector.css, source.css"
prop_name_scope = "meta.property-name.css, meta.property-name.scss"
prop_value_scope = "meta.property-value.css, meta.property-value.scss"
```

This is not really good, because each time there will be an update, it's gonna get overwritten. So best solution is still **@SergioAndrade's**

Matt